# Animated movie about a boy, a girl traveling through time and space in a ship called "The Tempest Fugit"

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel, cartoon

This is an older movie. I watched it sometime in my childhood so I'm guessing anywhere in between 1987 and 1995. I only remember a few details:

- The main characters are a boy and a girl
- The are guided somehow by an older man and this person is their only contact
- They travel in a ship called "**The Tempest Fugit**"
- I remember that they are somehow either lost or otherwise can't get back home. They may also just be stranded and not entirely in control of their ship.

The movie could be older than what I listed above. It may also be an animated series. I was quite young and can't remember many details.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Comment: As there is a time travel element: are you sure it was "Tempest Fugit" and not "Tempus Fugit"

Answer (score 9):

Everything BUT the timeframe you give points at:

[Valerian & Laureline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Val%C3%A9rian_and_Laureline)

The ships name (Tempus Fugit, instead of Tempest) checks out.
Boy and Girl check out.
Time and Space travel element check out.
Their commander is an older man, so this checks out.
Thanks to comment by Goufalite:  "Can't go back home" : Confirmed in Valerian & Laureline, they mess with an event in time which causes the future to change so they cannot get to their epoch, a futuristic city called Galaxity.

I am not able to find any hints of a Series or Movie adaption fitting your timeframe, though! The series was produces in 2007. Still, plotwise, this is my best guess. Considering childhood memories play tricks on us, this may actually be what you are looking for :).

Comment: There was a 2007 TV animated show called Time Jam.

Comment: "Can't go back home" : Confirmed in Valerian & Laureline, they mess with an event in time which causes the future to change so they cannot get to their epoch, a futuristic city called Galaxity.

Comment: @Valorum I suspected that one, too, but 2007 is a little too distant from 1995. So everything matches up except the production year... that is, unless someone took the Tempus Fugit and used her to transmit the series ;).

Comment: There was some pilots before the 2007 video so perhaps it was some of them.

Comment: @riccs_0x - Neither pilot ended up on TV

Comment: Right, but I didn't read it was on tv, it isn't specified. Besides, there were lots of video rentals before... I went to rent Beta  movies every weekend, so perhaps. But I agree it seems a bit weird, the year reference does not match.

Comment: This is most likely it. It's hard to believe. I swear I saw this growing up but there are too many things lining up here for that to be true. Memory is a weird thing.